# What is the available Windows azure internal bandwidth?

Tags: performance, azure, azure-sql-database

If I have a web role running an ASP.NET app accessing an Azure SQL database in the same availability zone (US East, for example), what is the bandwidth for the connection between the two? 100Mbs? 1Gbs? I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the I/O capacity for your server instance is dependent on the size of the instance. 1 core  / 100Mbps of IO.

Comment: Yes, that's on the web role side. What about the DB side though?

Comment: not a complete answer, but slide 8 on this presentation give you some hints: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2012/AZR302